# PyAutoGui Fails When I Open Putty with a Script

Tags: python, putty, pyautogui

#### Issues

I'm automating a putty session using Python. I'm using PyAutoGui to load my saved session. The script works perfectly fine when I manually open putty, then run the script. However, when I add Popen(putty.exe) to my code, I get the following error. I'm not sure why locateOnScreen would work when I'm opening putty manually vs opening it in the script. I tried using print screen and pyautoguis screenshot function instead of snippet tool, and that didn't work.

#### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\filepath\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    session_center = pyautogui.center(saved_session)
  File "C:\filepath\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 582, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

#### Code

```
import pyautogui
import os
from subprocess import Popen


home = os.path.expanduser('~')
corrected_path = home.replace(os.sep, '\\')
log_path = corrected_path + '\\PyAutoGuiPNGs\\'

Popen('putty.exe')

saved_session = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('saved_session.png', grayscale=True, confidence=.5)
session_center = pyautogui.center(saved_session)
pyautogui.moveTo(session_center)
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.click()

pyautogui.write('router')
load = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('load.png', grayscale=True, confidence=.5)
load_center = pyautogui.center(load)
pyautogui.moveTo(load_center)
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.click()

open_button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('open.png', grayscale=True, confidence=.5)
open_center = pyautogui.center(open_button)
pyautogui.moveTo(open_center)
pyautogui.PAUSE = 1
pyautogui.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the issue. PyAutoGui was trying to find the Putty window before it opened. Adding sleep(0.1) after the Popen('putty.exe') solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Putty isn't crashing PyAutoGUI. PyAutoGUI is failing to locate the reference image you're providing, returning `None`. Then you're asking PyAutoGUI to calculate the center of `None`. Given `None` isn't a pair of coordinates and center is expecting tuple of 4 integers `(left, top, width, height)`, it is unable to calculate, resulting in a crash.

You fix this by determining why you're failing to locate `saved_session.png` and either modifying your target image, or adding additional logic to allow you to locate it.